# What current methods are there to gain access to Azure?

Tags: authentication, attacks, azure

I'm currently working with our development teams and trying to build a threat model for the Azure environment and how attackers may gain access to our instance.

So far I haven't found much in the way of documentation and my own research has only come up with a single method that will get around MFA but requires a chain of attacks to be successful.

So my question is - should I only be modeling known authentication attacks or are there other methods for attacking on premise and via the azure portal?

Comment: You could try to gain client secret and client ID in Azure. These things are important to gaining access to Azure resources.